# I need help on Buying a Bicycle

Tags: product-rec, single-speed, fitness, exercise

I want to buy a bicycle for losing weight. I need a single speed one, though my budget is Narrow (like too narrow). Please help me what type of bike should I buy.

Comment: IMO, You primarily loose weight by consuming less calories that your body burns; you use your bicycle to get/stay in shape.

Comment: You don't really need a single speed. You will probably be best served by getting a used, rigid body (no shocks/springs) steel frame mountain bike and swapping the tires to something without the knobbies.

Comment: If you aren't already in good shape,  I would probably advise against a single speed. They aren't that much cheaper than a multispeed bicycle, and they only have 1 gear so you either can't climb hills, or you can't go very fast on flats.  If you are fit enough, you can do both, but hills are still quite strenuous.

Comment: Your budget probably eliminates anything trendy like a singlespeed.  For $50 you should be able to find a workable hybrid bike and start from there.  Or, ask around and someone may have/know of a free one.

Comment: On loosing weight - you need to increase your energy expenditure (work) and maintain or decrease energy input (food)  Stick to plain old water for hydration.

Comment: I suggest looking for your local bike co-op. They may be able to help with a cheap bike, and the social aspect is an important part to motivate you in achieving your goals.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys Im from india so its quite a mixed terrain of rocks, gravel, and sand, im going to my local bike shop tomorrow. I looked up at the mall and found a MaxIt worth $60. I guess ill have a look at the local shop or else ill go fofr the MaxIt. Thanks a lot Lads!!

Answer (score 1):

This is a sticky one to tackle. Firstly, we don't know the terrain you're riding in, we don't know if you're going to commute to work/school/college/university and we don't even know exactly what your budget would be. As for a Single-Speed, why specifically? You could lose weight on a road racer or a mountain bike, or even a BMX.

Anyhow, if your budget is low, you can look on eBay and try your luck, or you could perhaps buy a bike from a local bike-shop that has been refurbished. I personally always buy refurbished bikes because they're a fair bit cheaper than new.

For a cheap bike, don't go for ranges like Sports Direct or Tesco's or any other superstore bikes like that, as they're usually badly made and have little to no grease in any bearings, which is very bad! Just look at BikeMan4U on YouTube to see what I mean.

A fixie with a Flip-Flop hub would be good, as it gives you a choice of what you'd prefer to run around on.